# When have I got to divide a view into others two?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, listview, mvvm, viewmodel

This is the view which I doubt. Please, see the above part.

Someone has to browse a file (zip or xml file). If this one is a zip, the list view below must extract all the files from the filename browsed. If it's a xml file, it should be only one item into the listview. And then the user must press Upload Button, and get each one file from a list (I guess an observable collection), after the program will be updating and refreshing the values (Status).

What do you think? Is it necessary to create two view models and two views?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily handle all in one, because you have really few controls on the UI. And use visibility bindings to hide/show them.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't.  I would handle how the collection bound to the ListView is generated.  A file object is a file object regardless of if it's been extracted or not.  So all you have to do is add logic to investigate if it's a zip file, fill the observable collection with the files to be extracted.  If not, add the single xml file to the collection.